# How to save multiple animations into one in matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I made an animation showing the changing electric (quiver) field of a moving charge as well as some changing texts showing some math values. However, in order to show these different changing things, I had to use four FuncAnimation functions: one for the moving charge, one for the quiver field, one for the upper text, one for the lower text. My question is: how can I save everything into one mp4 file? I searched for similar topics, but they all have only one FuncAnimation function, which can be easily saved by calling things like anim.save('anim.mp4',writer=writer).

```
anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=100,interval=10,blit=False)
animm=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,updata_quiver,fargs=(Q,x,y),frames=100,interval=10,blit=False)
animmm=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,updatetext1,frames=100,interval=10,blit=False)
animmmm=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,updatetext2,frames=100,interval=10,blit=False)
```

This is what it looks like after compiling:

[image]

Comment: interesting question. I'd be curious to know if there is a way to do that. On the other hand, are you sure 4 `FuncAnimation` are necessary? I don't see (but I could be wrong, we'd need to see your code) why you couldn't use one animation to do the whole job. And then your problem would be solved.

Comment: To echo @DizietAsahi's comment, do you know that you can update more than one artist (plot element) in the same animation?  Seems like that would do it...

Comment: Really? I thought one FuncAnimation corresponds to only one update function! Could you please show me how to combine these into one? @Ajean

Comment: Yes, one update function, but you can update multiple things inside that function.  And, no, I can't show you how if you don't *post your code*.

Comment: @Ajean Thank you. Your instruction is pretty clear. I'll see if I can figure it out by myself. If not, I'll paste the code here.

Comment: Sounds good! You can [edit] your question to include it if you get stuck.

Comment: I made it. The trick is to combine all update functions into one and return a tuple of objects that need updating. Thanks Ajean and Diziet.